# How to exclude data members from JSON/XML serialization during runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

I have a list of strings in my web.config that describes the names of the model members (generated by Entity Framework) that are allowed to be serialized in my web api. 
How do I e.g. set the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute during runtime? 
The idea is, that not all the data should be exposed and the configuration what should be exposed, should be configurable without recompilation. 
So far, I am just setting all the values of the members not contained in that list to `null`. But this solution is not optimal because e.g. members of type `datetime` are serialized to `"0001-01-01T00:00:00"` and in addition, the response contains a lot of unnecessary information (the responses can grow up to 150MB). So it would be nicer to simply remove the members from the serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attributes:

`[XmlIgnore]` for XML or `[JsonIgnore]` for JSON.

For example:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

or

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, don't forget to use `System.Xml.Serialization` or `Newtonsoft.Json` respectively.

Comment: `[IgnoreDataMember]` works for both, I know that. But this has to be set on runtime depending on the configuration...

Comment: I see. You could write your own JSON converter that can use your conditionals at runtime. Another post that might help: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397494/web-api-conditional-serialization-of-properties-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it with `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`. So all my properties which are set to null are not included in the response. However, this is not the best solution because now I can't send any null values and swagger also shows the full model.